# How do I receive edn using a POST handler in Clojure? (and how do I send it)

Tags: http, clojure, clojurescript, edn

I am sending a map via a POST using `cljs-http` and I want to receive it with a Compojure POST handler and store it in a database. I'm totally confused as what I am supposed to do with the map in transit... there are a lot of options... `pr-str`, `prn`, `read-string` and on and on. On the sending side, it seems `cljs-http` might coerce my map into edn on it's own.  I have no way of knowing without a working Compojure handler.
Actually, to be honest, I'm still a bit unclear on what edn is. It's Clojure's data format, that I gather. As far as I can tell, what I am dealing with is actually just converting edn into a string format for shipping and back out. However, the :data value on the request is an object, not a string. A working example of a `cljs-http` POST and a Compojure POST handler that allows me to work with the original map sent by the client would be awesome. I don't know the purpose of `:edn-params` in my

```
(http/post "/test" (:edn-params (prn-str {:hey "there"})))
```

or if I should be using something else. I am used to JSON and am wondering if I should just be converting the data to JSON and back out on the receiving side. I'm unsure of the advantages of using edn.

On the receiving side I have:

```
(defroutes handler
  (GET "/about" [] "<h1>Hello World</h1>")
  (POST "/test" req (prn (read (:body req))))
  (route/not-found "<h1>Page not found</h1>"))
```

I know this likely wrong... but I thought I'd share where I am at.

UPDATE: After some thought, the title should have been 'What is the best way to send maps between a Reagent app and a server?". I just need to be able to send a map to a server, and make requests to that server and get a map back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is typical to encode EDN using [Transit](https://github.com/cognitect/transit-format) for HTTP transfer. Support for content (HTTP body) encoding and decoding is commonplace in clients and servers.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/r0man/cljs-http#content-type) for `cljs-http`, to POST a request using Transit+JSON i.e. `content-type` is `application/transit+json`:

```clj
(http/post "http://example.com" {:transit-params {:key1 "value1" :key2 "value2"}})
```

In a [Ring](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring)-compliant server, you would typically use middleware to deal with content format negotiation, content encoding and decoding. You could use [metosin/muuntaja](https://github.com/metosin/muuntaja) which supports JSON, EDN and Transit. There's a [code sample](https://cljdoc.org/d/metosin/muuntaja/0.6.8/doc/with-ring) which shows how to use it in the context of a Ring-compliant server.

[EDN](https://github.com/edn-format/edn) is a subset of Clojure, typically used when conveying values between Clojure(Script) programs. It is possible to use `application/edn` as a HTTP content type, but to do so would miss out on the huge support and processing optimisation that JSON content has.

A naïve translation from EDN to JSON leads to questions around how things like Clojure keywords, sets, etc. are handled. [Transit](https://github.com/cognitect/transit-format) resolves these issues by defining an open format (and libraries) where any values can be encoded. In particular, it enables EDN to be encoded to a JSON (or MessagePack) format. Put another way, the conveyed EDN piggybacks on JSON while in transit.

Comment: This was tremendously helpful... thank you! You got me going again on this project.

Comment: I'm very relieved to learn how simple it is to test a wrapped handler as shown in the example [https://cljdoc.org/d/metosin/muuntaja/0.6.8/doc/with-ring](https://cljdoc.org/d/metosin/muuntaja/0.6.8/doc/with-ring)